# Confusion abou how R computes standard error

Tags: r, linear-regression, standard-deviation, standard-error

I recently want to run a standard error of Fama-Macbeth test, when we compute standard error, we need standard devation. This test's sd is \frac{1}{n^2}\sum (x_i-\bar x)^2. In my mind, the denominator is n for a normal computation of sd. So my question is, whether a program , such as R and Eviews, when they run a linear regression they also give the coefficients' standard error by sd who is computed by denominator \frac{1}{n^2} ?

Thanks for everyone.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you are asking, but I think you want to know if `sd` uses `n` or `n-1` in the denominator. You can read about how functions work with `?` so `?sd` should be pretty helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The formula for calculating the standard error of coefficients in a linear regression can be found in introductory textbooks or e.g. [How are the standard errors of coefficients calculated in a regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/44838/126864).

The variance of the coefficients is given by

[image]

where sigma-hat-squared is the sum of squared residuals divided by the degrees of freedom, given by *n-k-1*, where *n* is the number of observations, *k* is the number of covariates, and assuming that the model has an intercept.

We can verify this empirically.  Using the built-in `mtcars` dataset

```
fit <- lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars)
```

we can see that

```
vcv <- (sum(fit$residuals^2)/(nrow(mtcars) - 2)) *
  solve(t(model.matrix(fit)) %*% model.matrix(fit))
all.equal(summary(fit)$coefficients[, "Std. Error"],
          sqrt(diag(vcv)))
# [1] TRUE
```